# Assigning values to matrix in R - values go in every row at different columns

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

```
nr <- 2
nc <- 4
rxc <- nr*nc
m1 <- Matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = rxc, sparse = TRUE)
col <- 0
for(r in 1:nr){
  m1[r,((r-1)*nc+1) :(((r-1)*nc+1)+3)] <- 1
  col <- col+1
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[1,] 1 1 1 1 . . . .
[2,] . . . .    1 1 1 1
```

This works, but its very slow as I have to do it for 10 Million rows. Is there any better way do it in R ?

Answer (score 3):

Use matrix indexing, which uses a two column matrix of row/column to determine which cells are changed:

```
m1[cbind(rep(1:nr,each=nc),1:(nr*nc))] <- 1
m1
#2 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                    
#[1,] 1 1 1 1 . . . .
#[2,] . . . . 1 1 1 1
```